# How can two web applications use same Servlet in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml, servletcontextlistener

I have two web applications. Both needs to use the same Servlet which is in a .jar that is under Tomcat /lib directory.

What should I do to achieve this?

In web.xml of one web application there is this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jwebsocket.tomcat.ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jWebSocket</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jwebsocket.tomcat.TomcatServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jWebSocket</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jWebSocket</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This works for one web application. What about the other?
Simply writing the same in its web.xml, with/without different url-pattern didn't work.
With "didn't work" I mean, although it seems to be deployed, it is not started by ContextListener.

Comment: You can have two WARs deployed with the same servlet (which could be available in the Tomcat lib folder or as a JAR included in both WARs). The `url-pattern` is always relative to the application context.

Comment: +1 for comment, which could be an answer as well.

Comment: Don't, ever, put application classes in Tomcat/lib. Put them in your war. That's what allows undeploying, redeploying, and having two different versions of the same class in two separate applications.

Comment: @JB Nizet I would like to. However that was the way that was told by user-guide of application. Still I tried to put in .war but caused other problems. By the way, as answer of my question; I have written my own ContextListener, and I saw that it enters to both ContextListener but the external .jar does not allow to run 2 copies at the same time.